# Mongoid count/size on query returns a floating point number instead of intenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I just upgraded to Mongoid 5.0.0.beta and Mongo 2.1.0.beta, and counting number of records for a query is returning a floating point, not integer. Is this expected behavior of Mongoid 5.0.0.beta/Mongo 2.1.0.beta?

```
irb(main):004:0> Post.where(:created_at.gt => 1.day.ago).count
=> 359.0
irb(main):004:0> Post.where(:created_at.gt => 1.day.ago).size
=> 359.0
```

Comment: There is a `JIRA` ticket for this - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1042. And it has been fixed in 2.1.1. Please see if it helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not show any kind of research by the OP.

Comment: Well, your research-fu is definitely better than mine. My research on Google  and stackoverflow didn't yield the same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is actually answer by @BatScream. It was fixed in Mongo Ruby driver v2.1.1. Fix was to upgrade mongoid gem to to latest version, 5.1.0, which has dependency on mongo driver v2.1.2.